# show numbers starting from 1 based on a cell value using vba

Tags: excel, vba

show numbers starting from 1 based on a cell value using vba.

For example, if you type 4 in cell A1, then range D1,D2,D3,D4 should display 1,2,3,4 respectively. If type 5 in cell A2, then range D1,D2,D3,D4,D5 should display 1,2,3,4,5.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: You should make an attempt before posting on SO.  Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You will need vba in a worksheet change event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below macro uses a worksheet change event to detect changes to the cell `A1`,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" And IsNumeric(Range("A1")) Then
        Dim i As Long
        Columns(4).ClearContents
        For i = 1 To Cells(1, 1)
            Cells(i, 4) = i
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gowtham!.. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @manu35 Thats nice!! Please mark this answer as correct to make this resolved. Thats how you tell Thanks here in SO :)